# Windows doesn't send DHCP Request after DHCP Offer

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp

I'm just at a friends place and we have problems with the WiFi.

Scenario is, there are (about) 8 Android devices, all without any problems logged in to the WiFi and connected to the internet.

Also, there are two notebooks, which both had problems even connecting to the network. After changing from pure WPA2/AES to WPA/WPA2 with AES/TKIP, both notebooks connected.

The second one had no problems connecting to the network and obtaining an IP address over DHCP, but the first one just connected and, according to the router log, didn't answer the DHCP offer. When setting a fixed IP address, everything works.

Any ideas, why the notebook didn't send a DHCP Request? This is just confusing me.

Thanks in advance,
Wolle

Comment: since your logs are router-side, its likely that the device did not receive the offer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dhcp client is started in Windows services, which can be found when you search in the search field above start.

Comment: If the DHCP client isn't running it would request a DHCP offer in the first place....